# The Minimum of a Sum of Continuous functions

Tags: calculus, inequality

Suppose you have two continuous functions:
$ f, g : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$
and you already know that a lower bound for $(f+g)$ is $0$---that is, $(f+g)(x)>0, \forall \; x \in [0, \infty)$.

Would it be possible to have min($f$)+min($g$)$ < 0$?

If so, what must be done to guarantee that min($f$)+min($g$) $>0$?

Comment: What about $f=x$ and $g=1-x$, where $f+g\equiv 1$? And by $\min(f)$, do you mean the minimum over the whole domain?

Comment: Yes I did mean the minimum over the whole domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be possible to have min(f)+min(g)<0?

Consider $f(x) = x^2-4x+3$ and $g(x) = x^2-10x+24$

Then $(f+g)(x)=2x^2-14x+27$

and $(min)(f+g) = (f+g)(3.5)=2.5 > 0$

but $\min(f)=f(2)=-1 < 0$

and $\min(g)=g(5)=-1 < 0$

so, yes it's possible.

> what must be done to guarantee that min(f)+min(g) >0?

No condition on $f+g$ can ensure $\min(f)+\min(g)>0$

Suppose we have a function $h(x)$ with $\min(h)>0$

Let $h_1(x) = (2-x)(h(x)+1) + (x-1)(-1)$

and $h_2(x) = (2-x)(-1) + (x-1)(h(x)+1)$

then $(h_1 +h_2)(x) = (2-x)h(x) + (x-1)h(x)= h(x)$

and $h_1(2)=-1$, $h_2(1)=-1$

So, any non-negative function can be split into two functions each of which isn't non-negative.